# Registering form is not storing data in database

Tags: html, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Well I am using this form to register a user in database but It is not successfully being storing data. While **RegisterContoller.php** is in **Auth** section. And I have given route: **Auth::routes();**. But still I why it is not storing data.

**Register.blade.php**

```
         <form style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; margin-top: 5%;" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group organic-form-2 {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label for="name">Your Name *</label>
              <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

              @if ($errors->has('name'))
                <span class="help-block">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                </span>
              @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group organic-form-2 {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label for="email">Your Email *</label>
              <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group organic-form-2">
              <label>Password *</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group organic-form-2">
              <label>Repeat Password *</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group remember-me">
              <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="value1"> Privacy Policy Agreement?
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group footer-form">
              <button class="btn btn-brand pill" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
   protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you miss input names in your form.

Instead of:

```
<div class="form-group organic-form-2">
  <label>Password *</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group organic-form-2">
  <label>Repeat Password *</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="Password">
</div>
```

use:

```
<div class="form-group organic-form-2">
  <label>Password *</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="Password" name="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group organic-form-2">
  <label>Repeat Password *</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="Password" name="password_confirmation">
</div>
```

Comment: Also the create method should have something like this:



public function create(){
      if(!$this->validator())
         return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors();
}